# Add pictures to a custom list programatically in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: list, image-upload

I am trying to upload a picture to a Picture column in a custom sharepoint list programatically.I am ok with using either client or server object models. All the examples I've seen so far only address uploading files to document/picture libraries.In my case I need to do it in a custom list.
Any ideas how to go about doing this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just to make it clear, you cant directly upload the image to the list! well thats what i know off!,

you need two steps...

1) upload the image to an image library

2) update the list with the image url

step one can be done through code by:

```
SPContext.Current.Web.Files.Add(String.Concat(SPContext.Current.Web.Site.RootWeb.Url, path), stream, true);
```

> path is relative path for the image. in user case file name. stream
>   can get using FileUpload.FileContent in file upload control
>
> Then add this path to the list as below.

```
listItem["Image"] = path;
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13602717/cannot-upload-image-to-a-sharepoint-list

or

```
FieldUrlValue _url = new FieldUrlValue();
_url.Url = txtImgUrl.Text;
_url.Description = txtImgTitle.Text;
listItem["Image"] = _url;
```

client side you could do somthing like:

```
        ClientContext context = new ClientContext(Url);
        List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(ImageList);
        CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
        query.ViewXml = "<View/>";

        ListItemCollection listItems = list.GetItems(query);

        context.Load(listItems);

        context.ExecuteQuery();

        ListItem item = listItems[listItems.Count+1];

        item["Title"] = txtTitle.Text;

        ((Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUrlValue)(item["ImageUrl"])).Url = txtImgUrl.Text;
        ((Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUrlValue)(item["ImageUrl"])).Description = txtImgTitle.Text;

        item.Update();
        context.ExecuteQuery();
```

call the list as usual, difference is here! the list item column is a "hyperlink or picture", in this case its a picture that takes in a url of the image and text for description! what i did in client side can easily be repeated! it becomes:

get the list as usual (call spsite then spweb then splist), add list item as usual but by doing it thisway! `SPFieldUrlValue` is the type and `item` is `SPListItem` from `SPList` :).

```
((SPFieldUrlValue)(item["ImageUrl"])).Url = path;

((SPFieldUrlValue)(item["ImageUrl"])).Description = description;
```

the varible `path` and `description` is whatever or whereever your getting the values from!

as you can see there are a few ways! I like the last way as its easy to understand and doesnt take long to code(less space!), dont forget to update the list and spweb!